# play flexslider on hover?

Tags: jquery, each, flexslider

How can I first stop flexslider and then play it on hover? And extra challenge theres multiple on the same page. This works BUT

1. it crashes jquery and nothing works after (some markup i missed?)
2. if user jumps to another tab on the browser all dozen flexsliders start to play simultaneously (is this because window load or what - this does not happen on page load only when switching back from another browser tab)

   ```
   $(window).load(function() {

   $('.preview').each(function(index){

   if($(".preview").eq(index).length) {

   $('.preview').eq(index).flexslider({
       slideshowSpeed: 225,
       animationSpeed: 150,
       initDelay: 0,  
       useCSS: true,
       animation: "fade",
       controlNav: false,
       directionNav: false,
       start: function(slider) {
           $('.preview').removeClass('loading');
           slider.pause();
           slider.manualPause = true;
           slider.mouseover(function() {
               slider.manualPause = false;
               slider.play();
           });
           slider.mouseout(function() {
               slider.manualPause = true;
               slider.pause();
           });
       },
       keyboard: false 
   });

   }

   })

   });
   ```
3. The answer below is perfect if you have one slider but i have multiple on the same page.

(I'm also pretty sure that eq does nothing really or is not setup correctly)

Comment: It is impossible to figure out what is issue without example. Can you reproduce the same issue in jsfiddle?

Comment: ok simplified my question. HOW TO PLAY ANY FLEXSLIDER ON HOVER?

slider.pause(); works on start but there's no way of getting it to play on hover afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `start` callback from your initialisation and try this:

```
$(document).on("hover", ".flex-viewport img", function() {
    $('.preview').play();
}, function() {
    $('.preview').pause();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it. The answer is slideshow: false,

```
$('.preview').flexslider({
    slideshowSpeed: 225,
    animationSpeed: 150,
    slideshow: false,
    initDelay: 0,  
    useCSS: false,
    animation: "fade",
    animationLoop: false,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    controlNav: false,
    directionNav: false,
    start: function(slider) {
        $('.preview').removeClass('loading');
        slider.pause();
        slider.manualPause = true;
        slider.mouseover(function() {
            slider.manualPause = false;
            slider.play();
        });
        slider.mouseout(function() {
            slider.manualPause = true;
            slider.pause();
        });
    },
    keyboard: false 
});
```

Comment: Nevermind its not working. I tried to multiply this to another page and its crashing. No help from the code below either.

Comment: Use jcuenod's solution. Its better much better. Cheers!